# android - Unresolved reference : all method in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm so confused with these error while using Espresso.

This is my import :

```js
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso
import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Before
import sayurbox.com.oms.view.LoginActivity
import android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended
import android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents
import android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent
import sayurbox.com.oms.view.HomeActivity
```

I already add all of the dependencies :

```js
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.2'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:4.0.2"
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
```

This is the errors :

```js
Unresolved reference: test
Unresolved reference: junit
Unresolved reference: AndroidJUnit4
Unresolved reference: Test
Unresolved reference: assertEquals
Unresolved reference: InstrumentationRegistry
...
```

All of the reference is unresolved. can you help me guys?

Comment: `implementation` vs `testImplementation`? Then where is your java file located in?

Comment: app -> src -> androidTest -> java -> mypackagename.com.oms -> here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the solution, i think because i put my test in the default Instrumentation test directory so i need to change my Gradle 'testImplementation' syntax to 'androidTestImplementation' :

before :

```
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
```

After fixed :

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
```